# How to add style to a NumberPicker in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, styles, themes

I am trying to add a custom style to an Android NumberPicker. What I am trying to do is have the text displayed by the picker as white since by default (or according to the default theme on the device) I have it in black. The problem is that my app background is a dark color so I want the text to be white or something clear.

so I have something like this in my style.xml file :

```
<style name="myPicker">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

the textcolor attribute doesn't even exist on the NumberPicker widget but I just tried to add it so that my text color changes. It does not work of course. The only thing that can be customized on this widget seems to be the background

Now the question : how can we change the text color of the picker ?

if somebody has the same issue or has solved it then please let us know.

Answer (score 3):

I have found an "ugly" way to do it. Just get a reference to the child views of the number picker widget. There are three (3) child views : the upper arrow, the textview (containing the text or value to be displayed) and the lower arrow.

Let's say we have a Number picker called np

```
np.setValue(10);
np.setMinValue(5);
np.setMaxValue(50);
// retrieve the textview reference
TextView npTextView = (TextView) np.giftAmount.getChildAt(1); // since indexing begins at 0
npTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
    R.color.my_custom_color)
```

I know that's bad but it works ...